# Deploy Ml pipeline with new transformers failed , heroku , fastapi

Tags: python, machine-learning, heroku, deployment

I want to deploy a complete  ml pipeline "preprocess +ml" for   fraud detection data  to heroku .

Every thing work well with simple pipeline using sklearn transformers locally and on heroku :

https://github.com/DeepSparkChaker/FraudDetection_Fastapi

But when i add some new transformers , also every thing works well locally  but failed on Heroku .
Complete code  :
https://github.com/DeepSparkChaker/FraudDetection_Fastapi_VF

Heroku errors logs :

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202633+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202639+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202639+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202640+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202640+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202640+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202640+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202641+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202641+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 991, in _find_and_load

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202641+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202642+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202642+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 783, in exec_module

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202642+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202643+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/main.py", line 52, in

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202643+00:00 app[web.1]:     model = joblib.load(joblib_filename)

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202643+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 575, in load

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202643+00:00 app[web.1]:     obj = _unpickle(fobj)

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202644+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 504, in _unpickle

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202644+00:00 app[web.1]:     obj = unpickler.load()

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202644+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1212, in load

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202645+00:00 app[web.1]:     dispatchkey[0]

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202645+00:00 app[web.1]: KeyError: 118

2021-12-10T10:49:29.202877+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 10:49:29 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203433+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 10:49:29 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203434+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203434+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203435+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203435+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/workers.py", line 66, in init_process

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203435+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(UvicornWorker, self).init_process()

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203440+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203440+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203441+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203441+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203442+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203442+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203442+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203442+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203443+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203443+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203443+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203444+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203444+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203444+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203445+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203445+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 991, in _find_and_load

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203445+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203446+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203446+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 783, in exec_module

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203446+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203446+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/main.py", line 52, in

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203447+00:00 app[web.1]:     model = joblib.load(joblib_filename)

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203447+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 575, in load

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203447+00:00 app[web.1]:     obj = _unpickle(fobj)

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203448+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 504, in _unpickle

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203448+00:00 app[web.1]:     obj = unpickler.load()

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203448+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1212, in load

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203449+00:00 app[web.1]:     dispatchkey[0]

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203449+00:00 app[web.1]: KeyError: 118

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203661+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 10:49:29 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)

2021-12-10T10:49:29.842214+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 10:49:29 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 12 was terminated due to signal 15

2021-12-10T10:49:29.842270+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 10:49:29 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 11 was terminated due to signal 15

2021-12-10T10:49:29.842304+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 10:49:29 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15

2021-12-10T10:49:29.935720+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 10:49:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

2021-12-10T10:49:29.935760+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 10:49:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

2021-12-10T10:49:30.393071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed

2021-12-10T10:49:30.100316+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3

## I am looking for the reasons of this issues and how can i overcome it .

It's just related to heorku or it willl be the same issue if i deploy on AWS / Azure..ex
I am new for deployment , your feedback will be so helpful.
Also any ideas how to enhance the quality of code in order to be ready for production

Comment: What do you mean by : it works locally? Do you manage to run your Docker container locally ? or just your Python code ?

Comment: just my python code , on notebook or even docker .
I mean locally : in my laptop  env

Comment: @Pierre-Loic do you need other clarification ?

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: This type of problem usually occurs when you do not set the 'procfile' file properly or may be you have not defined the python version in 'runtime.txt'

Comment: @MdTausif , you can take a look  on github repo of my project , i have defined all requirement and runtime.txt .I think the problem is caused when we load  the trained pipeline with custmor transformers ? 
2021-12-10T10:49:29.203446+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 52, in

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203447+00:00 app[web.1]: model = joblib.load(joblib_filename)

2021-12-10T10:49:29.203447+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 575, in load.



NB : every thing work well on my laptop .

Comment: @Pierre-Loic, is there some thing not clear ?

Comment: You should have used a branch on Github instead of creating a new repository : it is much easier to analyse your changes